# Do I need to have a PopUpWindow or Dialog to get the right design explained at images

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-dialog, android-popupwindow

I am trying to show a `PopUpWindow` or a `Dialog` on button click.
It is shown but the problem is it is not like the design and it is not having a background like normal `Dialog`
I want to have a `Dialog` or `Popup` at activity bottom. Do I need to write when the `Dialog` or the `PopUpWindow` is shown or where ?
Or is it better to create a `Fragment` and then only to call that `Fragment` at `Activity`.

Below are my images

**1. Is the actual design**
**2. Like this must be shown.**

[image]

[image]

Below is my code.

`BookmarkActivity.class`

```
ivShareMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                        getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(
                        inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_share, null, false),
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        600,
                        true);
                pw.showAsDropDown(ivShareMenu);
                // The code below assumes that the root container has an id called 'main'

            }
        });
```

`dialog_fragment_share.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/layoutWithSharing"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="8.0dip">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layoutPrivateMode"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_right_round_white_btn"
            style="@style/DialogShareAdvLayout">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/ivIncognitoMenu" android:src="@drawable/menu_incognito_on"
                style="@style/DialogShareAdvIcon" />
            <TextView android:layout_marginLeft="8.0dip" android:text="@string/WBVFontIncognito"
                style="@style/DialogShareAdvTv" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/layoutNightMode"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_white_round_btn" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="12.0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" style="@style/DialogShareAdvLayout">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/ivNightMode" android:src="@drawable/night_button"
                style="@style/DialogShareAdvIcon" />
            <TextView android:ellipsize="end" android:id="@+id/tvNightMode"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8.0dip" android:text="@string/WBVNightModeNight"
                android:lines="1" style="@style/DialogShareAdvTv" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ivTextSearch"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_left_round_white_btn"
            style="@style/DialogShareAdvLayout">
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp" style="@style/DialogShareAdvIcon" />
            <TextView android:layout_marginLeft="8.0dip" android:text="@string/WBVFindInPage"
                style="@style/DialogShareAdvTv" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="8.0dip" android:paddingRight="16.0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:minHeight="@dimen/share_layout_min_width">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/ivResetFont" android:background="@drawable/selector_gray_btn"
                android:paddingLeft="8.0dip" android:paddingRight="8.0dip" android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="42.0dip" android:layout_height="42.0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/font_icn" />
            <TextView android:textSize="13.0sp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2.0dip" android:text="@string/WBVFontSize" />
            <SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekBarFont" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:max="100" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
            <TextView android:textSize="14.0sp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:id="@+id/tvFontSize" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View style="@style/GrayDivider" />
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/shareLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/vgAddFavour" style="@style/DialogShareLayout.vertical">
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/action_add_favorites"
                    style="@style/DialogShareImgViewShare.Big" />
                <TextView android:text="@string/WBVAddToBookmarks" style="@style/DialogShareText.Big" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/vgAddReadable" style="@style/DialogShareLayout.vertical">
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/action_add_readinglist"
                    style="@style/DialogShareImgViewShare.Big" />
                <TextView android:text="@string/WBVAddToReadingList"
                    style="@style/DialogShareText.Big" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/vgCopyLink" style="@style/DialogShareLayout.vertical">
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/action_copylink"
                    style="@style/DialogShareImgViewShare.Big" />
                <TextView android:text="@string/WBVCopyLink" style="@style/DialogShareText.Big" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/vgShare" style="@style/DialogShareLayout.vertical">
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/action_share_url"
                    style="@style/DialogShareImgViewShare.Big" android:visibility="visible"/>
                <TextView android:text="@string/WBVShare" style="@style/DialogShareText.Big" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View style="@style/GrayDivider" />
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/share_layout_min_width">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/vgDownLoadList" android:paddingLeft="2.0dip"
                android:layout_weight="11.0" style="@style/DialogShareLayout.horizontal">
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/action_download_list"
                    style="@style/DialogShareImgViewShare.Small" />
                <TextView android:text="@string/WBVDownloadList" style="@style/DialogShareText.Small" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/vgSettings" android:layout_weight="11.0"
                style="@style/DialogShareLayout.horizontal">
                <ImageView android:paddingRight="4.0dip" android:src="@drawable/action_settings"
                    style="@style/DialogShareImgViewShare.Small" />
                <TextView android:text="@string/SVTitle" style="@style/DialogShareText.Small" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/vgQuit" android:paddingRight="10.0dip"
                android:layout_weight="12.0" style="@style/DialogShareLayout.horizontal">
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/action_quit"
                    style="@style/DialogShareImgViewShare.Small" />
                <TextView android:text="@string/WBVQuit" style="@style/DialogShareText.Small" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View style="@style/GrayDivider" />
        <Button android:id="@id/btnCancel" android:text="@string/WBVHideMenu"
            style="@style/DialogLoadingButton" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`bookmark_layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    style="@style/MainLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linBrowser"
        style="@style/BrowserLayout">



        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayoutSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/vpBrowsers"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:background="@color/downloadText" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/My_btn"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/ivBackground"
                style="@style/ImageViewBlockWebView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/backPanel"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@color/gray_alpha">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layoutCopyPast"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4.0dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4.0dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="4.0dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnPaste"
                            style="@style/CopyPastPanelButtons"
                            android:text="@string/SearchPage_Panel_Paste" />

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/firstDivider"
                            style="@style/CopyPastPanelDivider" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnCopy"
                            style="@style/CopyPastPanelButtons"
                            android:text="@string/SearchPage_Panel_Copy" />

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/secondDivider"
                            style="@style/CopyPastPanelDivider" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnCut"
                            style="@style/CopyPastPanelButtons"
                            android:text="@string/SearchPage_Panel_Cut" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layoutExtension"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center|left"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16.0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="16.0dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/ibShare"
                        style="@style/ImageButtonContext.Share" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/trendMainLayout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <include layout="@layout/trend_frame" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layoutCopy"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4.0dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4.0dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:visibility="gone">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnPasteTrend"
                            style="@style/CopyPastPanelButtons"
                            android:text="@string/SearchPage_Panel_Paste" />

                        <View style="@style/CopyPastPanelEmpty" />

                        <View style="@style/CopyPastPanelEmpty" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linLayoutBrowserPanel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/search_height"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/brPanelDivider"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1.0px"
                    android:background="@color/browserPanel" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/searchTextLayout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@color/blue_title"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="2.0dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2.0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="2.0dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="2.0dp"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ivCloseTextSearch"
                        style="@style/ViewGroupButtonBrowser.Small">

                        <ImageView
                            style="@style/SearchBtnNext"
                            android:src="@drawable/selector_close_white_24dp" />
                    </FrameLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2.0dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2.0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:background="@drawable/white_round_button"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:paddingLeft="8.0dp"
                        android:paddingTop="8.0dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8.0dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="8.0dp">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/etTextSearch"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1.0"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:hint="@string/WBVFindInPage"
                            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                            android:privateImeOptions="nm"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
                            android:textSize="14.0sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvSearchCount"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8.0dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/gray"
                            android:textSize="14.0sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ivPrevFind"
                        style="@style/ViewGroupButtonBrowser.Small">

                        <ImageView
                            style="@style/SearchBtnNext"
                            android:src="@drawable/selector_keyboard_arrow_left_white_24dp" />
                    </FrameLayout>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ivNextFind"
                        style="@style/ViewGroupButtonBrowser.Small">

                        <ImageView
                            style="@style/SearchBtnNext"
                            android:src="@drawable/selector_keyboard_arrow_next_white_24dp" />
                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linLayoutBrowserPanelSettings"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linLayoutBrowserBack"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="@color/blue_title"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <LinearLayout
                            style="@style/SideLayoutBrowserPanel"
                            android:layout_weight="6.0">

                            <FrameLayout
                                android:id="@+id/imgBtnPreviousPage"
                                style="@style/ViewGroupButtonBrowser.Side">

                                <ImageButton
                                    android:id="@+id/ivPrevPage"
                                    style="@style/ImageButtonBrowser"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrowleft_browser_tr" />
                            </FrameLayout>

                            <FrameLayout
                                android:id="@+id/imgBtnNextPage"
                                style="@style/ViewGroupButtonBrowser.Side">

                                <ImageButton
                                    android:id="@+id/ivNextPage"
                                    style="@style/ImageButtonBrowser"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrowright_browser_tr" />
                            </FrameLayout>

                            <FrameLayout
                                android:id="@+id/imgBtnVisHistory"
                                style="@style/ViewGroupButtonBrowser.Side">

                                <ImageButton
                                    style="@style/ImageButtonBrowser"
                                    android:src="@drawable/selector_visual_history" />
                            </FrameLayout>

                            <FrameLayout
                                android:id="@+id/imgBtnOpenReading"
                                style="@style/ViewGroupButtonBrowser.Side">

                                <ImageButton
                                    style="@style/ImageButtonBrowser"
                                    android:src="@drawable/selector_bookmarks_browser" />
                            </FrameLayout>

                            <FrameLayout
                                android:id="@+id/imgBtnShare"
                                style="@style/ViewGroupButtonBrowser.Side">

                                <ImageButton
                                    android:id="@+id/ivShareMenu"
                                    style="@style/ImageButtonBrowser"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="-2.0dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="2.0dp"
                                    android:paddingBottom="0.0dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/selector_action_reading_list" />
                            </FrameLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            style="@style/SideLayoutBrowserPanel"
                            android:layout_weight="11.0">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/imgBtnRead"
                                style="@style/ViewGroupButtonBrowser.Side"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                                android:gravity="center">

                                <ImageButton
                                    android:id="@+id/imgBtnDef"
                                    style="@style/ImageButtonBrowser"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="-12.0dp"
                                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                                    android:scaleX="@dimen/browser_switch_scale"
                                    android:scaleY="@dimen/browser_switch_scale"
                                    android:src="@drawable/toolbar_switch_mobilizer_off" />

                                <Switch
                                    android:id="@+id/switcher"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:scaleX="@dimen/browser_switch_scale"
                                    android:scaleY="@dimen/browser_switch_scale"
                                    android:switchMinWidth="20.0dp"
                                    android:textOff=""
                                    android:textOn=""
                                    android:thumb="@drawable/toolbar_switch_knob"
                                    android:track="@drawable/switch_background" />

                                <ImageButton
                                    android:id="@+id/imgBtnReadable"
                                    style="@style/ImageButtonBrowser"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="-12.0dp"
                                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                                    android:scaleX="@dimen/browser_switch_scale"
                                    android:scaleY="@dimen/browser_switch_scale"
                                    android:src="@drawable/toolbar_switch_mobilizer_on" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <FrameLayout
                                android:id="@+id/imgBtnFullScreen"
                                style="@style/ViewGroupButtonBrowser.Side"
                                android:layout_marginRight="5.0dp"
                                android:paddingLeft="5.0dp">

                                <ImageButton
                                    style="@style/ImageButtonBrowser"
                                    android:src="@drawable/selector_fullscreen_on" />
                            </FrameLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgBtnFullScreenOff"
                style="@style/ImgTransparentBtnBrowser"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center|right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10.0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_fullscreen_off" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgBtnBack"
                style="@style/ImgTransparentBtnBrowser"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center|left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_fs_back" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Set text color and gravity for text alignment, set gravity center

Comment: @Athira Where to set text?

Comment: Share your style.xml file

Comment: <Button
                            android:gravity="center"/>